# Can E. Honda move forward in Street Fighter 2 for SNES while doing the Hundred Hand Slap?

Tags: street-fighter-series, street-fighter-ii

My colleague and I are having a debate as to whether or not he could move forward while performing the Hundred Hand Slap in the original Street Fighter II?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Street Fighter 2: The World Warrior**, E. Honda didn't move while using the Hundred Hand Slap, but in **Street Fighter 2: Turbo Hyper Fighting**, he could move slightly backward or forward during the move.

I've just tested this and was able to confirm.

Comment: @naspinski yeah, the reason for your argument might be that you've played more Street Fighter Turbo, while your colleague played the original SF2. Blame Capcom and their multiple revisions.

Answer (score 5):

No he can't move during the attack in the original version "Street Fighter II The World Warrior".

here is your complete answer regardless of version :

The World Warrior - Super NES : NO he can't move

Special Champion Edition : Yes E.Honda can move from this point on...

Turbo : YES e.Honda can move...

New Challengers : YES for E.Honda

In full:
E. Honda has mastered the art of the Sumo hand slap.

He can do it so well and so quickly, that his hands appear as a blur.

Starting in Champion Edition, Honda gains the ability to move while performing this technique.

However, in Super Street Fighter II Turbo, the method was changed. Using Light Punch makes him stand still, using Medium Punch makes him move forward slowly, and using Hard Punch makes him move forward quickly.

Sources : I play SF EVERYDAY + confirmation by  http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_II/Characters/E._Honda

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, you could, actually, but it was more of a ... slide towards the opponent?